# Как настроить VS Code для дебаггинга Си Mac

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Я хочу дебажить одиночный файл .c, как мне это сделать, если у меня чистый Visual Studio Code? Какой план действий, я пытался изменять launch.json файл:

```c
{
    // Используйте IntelliSense, чтобы узнать о возможных атрибутах.
    // Наведите указатель мыши, чтобы просмотреть описания существующих атрибутов.
    // Для получения дополнительной информации посетите: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "a.out",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Но при нажатии на отладка мне пишет это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, устал уже в онлайн компиляторах дебажить

Comment: @AlexF я ничего не делал, плохо понимаю англ, но возможно придется с гугл переводчиком переводить

Comment: Воспользуйтесь переводчиком DeepL, качество перевода гораздо выше остальных.

Comment: imho, даже при плохом знании английского, английские версии программ понятнее русских